# Covered Porch Support Concrete Crack

Tags: concrete, framing, foundation, outdoor, diy-vs-pro

The front step of my home is made of concrete, on which supports the overhang via two posts on each corner. One of the corners of the concrete has developed a good sized crack, and it's taking the post supporting the roof with it.

This has taken a little over 2 years to develop, and I would like to take action this spring to fix it. I'll probably get a local insured GC to handle it for me.

My Question: What should I be aware of with this porch? What steps would you take to possibly slow this down? Could I fix this on my own (with extra hands of course)?

[image: Home Sweet... Oh my goodness... That doesn't look safe.]

[image: Behold, the Grand Canyon]

[image: Profile Mugshot]

Comment: Until it's fixed, get some temporary support posts under the porch roof and resting on something solid or you could end up with even bigger repairs.

Answer (score 1):

Is that post directly above, leaning? If so, foundation is settling and that is a bigger problem. If not, then the crack has probably developed from water seeping into the concrete around the anchor that is holding the post, then the water freezes and cracks the wall. Fixing the concrete without sealing the crack around the post anchor, will allow water to seep back into wall, freeze and then crack the wall again.

"No" you can't slow it down and "no" you can't do it yourself. If the foundation is not settling, the best way is to remove the concrete that has cracked away from the main foundation and re-pour a new section of concrete to match existing. (You can't re-pin the broken portion back to the main foundation.)

Comment: Yup! That post is leaning out away from the house.

I imagine it's been a combination of both settling and water freezing occurring to create this crack. Thanks for the input!